# Long double 1.#QNAN

Tags: c

Running the code below from Chapter 2 of "An Introduction to the C Programming Language and Software Design" by Tim Bailey works fine in C4Droid on Android but using CodeBlocks with the GCC compiler in Windows gives -1.#QNAN0e+000 for the upper limit of long double (LDBL_MAX). I understand that to mean "there's no such number", but presumably that means wrong coding and not "there's no limit" (I believe the correct answer is 1.797693e+308).

So, possible reasons I've checked:

1. Typo: I don't see it (and I've also selected LDBL_MAX from the CodeBlocks editor).
2. Type mismatch: I don't think so (%e should be fine).
3. LDBL_MAX not included in float.h: It is included.

Any suggestions gratefully received

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("Integer range:\t\t%d\t%d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    printf("Long range:\t\t%ld\t%ld\n", LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);
    printf("Float range:\t\t%e\t%e\n", FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX);
    printf("Double range:\t\t%e\t%e\n", DBL_MIN, DBL_MAX);
    printf("Long double range:\t%e\t%e\n", LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX);
    printf("Float-Double epsilon:\t%e\t%e\n", FLT_EPSILON, DBL_EPSILON);
}
```

Comment: Dude is correct, time to submit errata to the author.

Comment: Also, you should read about [default argument promotions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6) (which the book regrettably does not mention)

Comment: BTW: the range of finite `double` is `-DBL_MAX, DBL_MAX`.  The smallest positive is `DBL_TRUE_MIN`.

Answer (score 3):

If you read e.g. [this `printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you will see that all floating points format without any modifiers (including plain `"%e"`) is for the type `double`.

If you want to print the value of a `long double` you need the `L` modifier prefix, as in `"%Le"`.

Mismatching format specifier and type leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've just tried that:   printf("Long double range:\t%Le\t%Le\n", LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX); and same result:   -1.#QNAN0e+000